# How to create a pivot table from a CSV file having subgroups and getting the count of the last values using shell script?

Tags: shell, awk

I want to group the columns then form subsequent group getting the count of last column values.
For example main Group A, Subgroup D, J , P and count of P in the subsequent groups as well as the total count of last column.
I am able to form groups but subgroup seems a little hard. Any help is appreciated like how to get this.

Input:

A,D,J,P
A,D,J,Q
A,D,K,P
A,D,K,P
A,E,J,Q
A,E,K,Q
A,E,J,Q
B,F,L,R
B,F,L,R
B,F,M,S
C,H,N,T
C,H,O,U
C,H,N,T
C,H,O,U

Output:

A D J P 1
         Q 1
      K P 2
A E J Q 2
      K Q 1
B F L R 2
      M S 1
C H N T 2
      O U 2
    Total   14

Comment: why do you have "A" shown on the 4th line?  It matches the above records' values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
!($0 in cnt) { recs[++numRecs] = $0 }
{ cnt[$0]++ }
END {
    for (recNr=1; recNr<=numRecs; recNr++) {
        rec = recs[recNr]
        split(rec,f)
        newVal = 0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if (f[i] != p[i]) {
                newVal = 1
            }
            printf "%s%s", (newVal ? f[i] : " "), OFS
            p[i] = f[i]
        }
        print cnt[rec]
        tot += cnt[rec]
    }
    print "Total", tot+0
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
A D J P 1
      Q 1
    K P 2
  E J Q 2
    K Q 1
B F L R 2
    M S 1
C H N T 2
    O U 2
Total 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach, a shell script that uses sqlite to calculate the group counts (Requires 3.25 or newer because it uses window functions):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
file="$1"
sqlite3 -batch -noheader <<EOF
CREATE TABLE data(c1 TEXT, c2 TEXT, c3 TEXT, c4 TEXT);
.mode csv
.import "$file" data
.mode list
.separator " "
SELECT (CASE c1 WHEN lag(c1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c1) THEN ' ' ELSE c1 END)
     , (CASE c2 WHEN lag(c2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY c1,c2 ORDER BY c1,c2) THEN ' ' ELSE c2 END)
     , (CASE c3 WHEN lag(c3, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY c1,c2,c3 ORDER BY c1,c2,c3) THEN ' ' ELSE c3 END)
     , c4
     , count(*)
FROM data
GROUP BY c1, c2, c3, c4
ORDER BY c1, c2, c3, c4;
SELECT 'Total ' || count(*) FROM data;
EOF
```

Running this gives:

```
$ ./group.sh example.csv
A D J P 1
      Q 1
    K P 2
  E J Q 2
    K Q 1
B F L R 2
    M S 1
C H N T 2
    O U 2
Total 14
```

Also a one-liner using [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), though it doesn't include the fancy output format:

```
$ datamash -st, groupby 1,2,3,4 count 4 < example.csv | tr , ' '
A D J P 1
A D J Q 1
A D K P 2
A E J Q 2
A E K Q 1
B F L R 2
B F M S 1
C H N T 2
C H O U 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

**Script**

```
perl -0777 -lne ' 
s/^(.+?)$/$x++;$kv{$1}++/mge; 
foreach my $k (sort keys %kv) 
    { $q=$c=$k; 
        while(length($p) > 0)
        {
        last if $c=~/^$p/g; 
        $q=substr($c,length($p)-1);
        $p=~s/(.$)//;
        }
    printf( "%9s\n", "$q $kv{$k}") ;
    $p=$k;
} 
print "Total $x";
' anurag.txt
```

**Output:**

```
A,D,J,P 1
      Q 1
    K,P 2
  E,J,Q 2
    K,Q 1
B,F,L,R 2
    M,S 1
C,H,N,T 2
    O,U 2
Total 14
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I have not *exactly* an answer that produces your example output but I'm close enough to dare posting an answer</strike>

Now I have an answer that produces *exactly* your example output... :-)

```
$ cat ABCD
A,D,J,P
A,D,J,Q
A,D,K,P
A,D,K,P
A,E,J,Q
A,E,K,Q
A,E,J,Q
B,F,L,R
B,F,L,R
B,F,M,S
C,H,N,T
C,H,O,U
C,H,N,T
C,H,O,U
$ awk '{a[$0]+=1}END{for(i in a) print i","a[i];print "Total",NR}' ABCD |\
  sort | \
  awk -F, '
    /Total/{print;next}
    {print a1==$1?" ":$1,a2==$2?" ":$2,a3==$3?" ":$3,a4==$4?" ":$4,$5
     a1=$1;a2=$2;a3=$3;a4=$4}'
A D J P 1
      Q 1
    K P 2
  E J Q 2
    K   1
B F L R 2
    M S 1
C H N T 2
    O U 2
Total 14
$
```

The first `awk` script iterates on every line and at every line we increment the value of an array, `a`, element, indexed by the whole line value, next at the end (`END` target) we loop on the indices of `a` to print the index and the associated value, that is the count of the times we have that line in the data - eventually we output also the total number of lines processed, that is automatically updated in the variable `NR`, **n**umber of **r**ecords.

The second `awk` script either prints the total line and skips any further processing or it compares each field (splitted on commas) with the corresponding field of the previous line and output the new field or a space accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll propose a multi stage solution in the spirit of unix toolset.

create a sorted, counted, de-delimited data format

```
$ sort file | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}' | tr ',' ' ' 

A D J P 1
A D J Q 1
A D K P 2
A E J Q 2
A E K Q 1
B F L R 2
B F M S 1
C H N T 2
C H O U 2
```

now, the task is removing the longest left common substring from consecutive lines

```
... | awk 'NR==1 {p=$0} 
           NR>1  {k=0; 
                  while(p~t=substr($0,1,++k)); 
                  gsub(/./," ",t); sub(/^ /,"",t); 
                  p=$0; $0=t substr(p,k)}1'


A D J P 1
      Q 1
    K P 2
  E J Q 2
    K Q 1
B F L R 2
    M S 1
C H N T 2
    O U 2
```

whether it's easier to understand than one script will be seen.